# Как распарсить errorBody в retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Добрый день!

Использую Retrofit2 в своем проекте. Не могу понять как использовать errorBody, когда в response падает код отличный от 200.

Есть метод:

```
@POST("request/1")
 Call<ResponseBody> example(
     @Body ExampleRequest exampleRequest
);
```

Дальше я дергаю его следующим образом:

```
ErrorReponse errorResponse; //здесь лежит моделька ошибки, условно POJO с 2 полями
Api api = service.getApi(); //пропустим http.builder
Response<ResponseBody> response;
try{
    response = api.example(new ExampleRequest()).execute();
}catch(Exception e){
    //...
}
if(response.isSuccessful()){
//пропустим эту ситуацию 
}else{
    String error = response.errorBody().string();
    errorResponse = Utils.parseErrorResponse(error);
    String errorMessage = errorResponse.getData().getErrors().getMessage();
    int errorCode = errorResponse.getData().getErrors().getCode();
}
```

Утильный метод parseErrorResponse выглядит так:

```
public static ErrorResponse parseErrorResponse(String errorResponse) {
    return new Gson().fromJson(errorResponse, ErrorResponse.class);
}
```

И что я не могу понять, так это то что приходит мне в errorBody. Когда я в первый раз вызываю метод response.errorBody().string(); В нем содержится [text=okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@6179551b]

вот содержимое в отладчике:
http://joxi.ru/KAxLzQPt49YQDA

Кто-нибудь сталкивался? Что нибудь посоветуйте пожалуйста.

Comment: а, что в отладчике вы видите в переменной `String error`?

Comment: @mit вот собственно название какого-то ретрофитовского объекта и вижу "okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@6179551b"